# Ajax does not execute success function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ajaxform, jquery-ajaxq

I have a jquery ajax function that submits form data to a php file where its checked against a database and returns the response. But my success function isn't being executed, instead the response is returned through the error function.

**Following is my login.js code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#loginForm").submit(function() { // loginForm is submitted
        var username = $('#username').attr('value'); // get username
        var password = $('#password').attr('value'); // get password

    if (username && password) { // values are not empty
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "url", // URL of the Php script
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json", //expected from server in response
            // send username and password to the Php script
            data: "username=" + username + "&password=" + password,


            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { // script call was *not* successful
                $('div#loginResult').text("responseText: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText
                + ", textStatus: " + textStatus
                + ", errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
                $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
            },

            success: function(data){ //script was successful, data contains response from mysql database
                if (data.error) { // login was not successful
                    $('div#loginResult').text("data.error: " + data.error);
                    $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
                } // if
                else { // login was successful
                    $('form#loginForm').hide();
                    $('div#loginResult').text("data.success: " + data.success);
                    $('div#loginResult').addClass("success");
                } //else
            } // success
        }); // ajax
    } // if
    else {
        $('div#loginResult').text("enter username and password");
        $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
    } // else
    $('div#loginResult').fadeIn();
    return false;
});
});
```

**This is my Login.php code:**

```
 <?php



$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];


$dbhost = '*****';
$dbuser = '*****';
$dbpass = '*****';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass); // connect to server
if(! $conn )
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo 'Connected to database successfully,';

mysql_select_db('sl493',$conn); //pick sl493 database


$result = mysql_query("SELECT *
        FROM metauser
        WHERE metauser.username = '$username'
        AND metauser.password = '$password'") or die(mysql_error()); //select data from metauser table

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if($row['username'] == $username) //If username and password not accepted
{$result = 'true login';
 $arr = array('success' => "login is successful");
 echo json_encode($arr);}

else //if username and password are not accepted
{$result = 'login failed';
 $arr = array('error' => "username or password is wrong");
 echo json_encode($arr);}

?>
```

Right now I get the following response regardless if i type correct or incorrect credentials:

responseText: Connected to database successfully,{"success":"login is successful"}
 , textStatus: parsererror, errorThrown: Invalid JSON: Connected to database successfully,{"success":"login is successful"}
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xynj.jpg

It returns "Connected to database successfully" which means it goes successfully to login.php but it also returns responseText which is part of ajax:error, where it shouldn't be going since function is executed successful.HALP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured what was wrong:

1. First I specified ContentType as json while i was sending it as a
   string so i had to change that.
2. Second I used the Is_set andis_empty function for $_POST to make
   sure i was getting the POST fields.
3. Finally the return ajax variable data for reason wouldn't display it
   by key, so data.success is undefined but data returns all the output
   from the php file.

I am still trying to figure out why i can't access the returned JSON by key. Please let me know if you have any suggestions, I don't to create another question. Following is the working code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#loginForm").submit(function() {

    // loginForm is submitted
        var username = $('#username').attr('value'); // get username
        var password = $('#password').attr('value'); // get password
        console.log(username + password) ;

        if (username && password) { // values are not empty
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://xxx/login.php", // URL of the Php script
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",

                dataType: "application/json", //expected from server in response
                // send username and password to the Php script
                //data: "username=" + username + "&password=" + password,
                data:'username='+ username+'&password='+ password,

                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { // script call was *not* successful
                    $('div#loginResult').text("responseText: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText
                    + ", textStatus: " + textStatus
                    + ", errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
                    $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
                },

                success: function(data){


                    $('form#loginForm').hide();
                    $('div#loginResult').text("Login: " + data );
                    $('div#loginResult').addClass("success");
                                                                }


            });
        }
        else {
            $('div#loginResult').text("enter username and password");
            $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
        } // else
        $('div#loginResult').fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
})
```

;

Login.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["username"]) && !empty($_POST["username"])) {
    $username = $_POST["username"];}

if (isset($_POST["password"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])) {
    $password = $_POST["password"];}

$dbhost = 'xxx';
$dbuser = 'xxxxxx';
$dbpass = 'xxxxxxxx';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass); // connect to server
if(! $conn )
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('sl493',$conn);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM metauser WHERE metauser.username = '$username'AND metauser.password = '$password'") or die(mysql_error()); //select data from metauser table
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);


if($row['username'] == $username)
{
        if($row['usertype']== 'student')
              { $type = 'student'; }
                    else{ $type = 'admin'; }

    //$arr = array('result' => 'loginOK', 'usertype' => $type);

    $associativeArray = array();
    $associativeArray ['result'] = 'success';
    $associativeArray ['usertype'] = $type;

    //$arr = '{"success":"login is successful"}';
    //echo $type;
    echo json_encode($associativeArray); }


else
{$arr = '{"error":"username or password is wrong"}';
    echo json_encode($arr);}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data="";
data=['username':username,'password':password];//Add this

 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "url", // URL of the Php script
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json", //expected from server in response
            // send username and password to the Php script
            data: JSON.stringify(data),//Stringify your data while sending
            success: function(data){ //script was successful, data contains response from mysql database
                if (data.error) { // login was not successful
                    $('div#loginResult').text("data.error: " + data.error);
                    $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
                } // if
                else { // login was successful
                    $('form#loginForm').hide();
                    $('div#loginResult').text("data.success: " + data.success);
                    $('div#loginResult').addClass("success");
                } //else
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { // script call was *not* successful
                $('div#loginResult').text("responseText: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText
                + ", textStatus: " + textStatus
                + ", errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
                $('div#loginResult').addClass("error");
            }, // success
        }); // ajax
```

Comment: it throws "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" at 
data=['username':username,'password':password];//Add this

Comment: @slk.. try this then `data={'username':username,'password':password};`

Comment: what you are getting now. can you debug and see what value has been passed in data??

Answer (score 0):

Please change your ajax data type from `dataType: "json"`  to

```
datatype: "application/json"
```

To solve the response header issue in case of unauthorised response please add response header as `header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized', true, 401);` in else part of the code as shown below.

```
else //if username and password are not accepted
{$result = 'login failed';
 $arr = array('error' => "username or password is wrong");
header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized', true, 401);
 echo json_encode($arr);}
```

Comment: still getting this: responseText: Connected to database successfully,["login is successful"]
 , textStatus: parsererror, errorThrown: Invalid JSON: Connected to database successfully,["login is successful"]

Comment: Change ajax datatype  from  [dataType: "json"] to

[datatype: "application/json"] and it should do the magic :)

Comment: Phew it worked, but not perfectly. I get: 
"data.success: undefined" with both correct and incorrect credentials. 
Which means it's getting into the success function but not able to deifferentiate between its different cases.

Comment: Its a different issue and can be achieved easily by setting php response header as below.     header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized', true, 401);

Comment: Care to elaborate more ? I don't have a lot of experience with php. Where in the code Am i supposed to place the header.

Comment: I have updated my answer. This should move ajax response to error section when unauthorized.

Comment: It didn't make a difference, I still get "data.success: undefined". I think it's unable to read the "success" key/value pair of the JSON.

Comment: Are you sure your code flow reaching else part ? Can you please verify that.

Comment: No i don't think it ever reaches the else part. I changed my javascript to this:
success: function(data){
                console.log(data);

And in the console I see: ["login is successful"] with both correct and incorrect credentials.

Comment: You need to check this line.    if($row['username'] == $username) //If username and password not accepted 
               Either your are not receiving valid value from client or your query result is not as expected.            Try var_dump() in both the variables and share the response.

Comment: I checked the php file individually and it is receiving $_POST properly, but I am not sure how to check if data sent from ajax.being received correctly in php. How do i use var_dump in php that i can see the data being sent by ajax ? Currently i use the inspect element console on chrome. 
Also thank you for the help, I am a beginner and really appreciate your help for trying to fix this.

Comment: Use it like mentioned below.
var_dump($_post);  
var_dump($row);
try exit(); function to stop the execution. Let me know if you need further help :) also you can accept the answer if it was helpful :P

Comment: I figured out what was wrong, now i just have an issue with accessing returned json by key. Please check my answers below, thanks.